# Espresso + Picasso + Spoon

Tags: android, unit-testing, mocking, picasso, android-espresso

Picasso is using threads for loading images in the background. Even when loading from assets, there'a a slight delay until it shows up, which causes the pictures not to appear on a capture with spoon. I could add a 1s sleep in the test, but I was wondering if there was a better way.

I tried to set a `Downloader` or a `RequestHandler` to return the image synchronously, but I think I need to set a `ExecutorService` that uses the main thread or an `AsyncTask` (such that espresso will wait). With retrofit, we can use `AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR` with `MainThreadExecutor` but I'm not sure how to do it for picasso.

As a workaround, I wrapped picasso in an ImageUtil which won't be used during instrumentation:

```
DebugModule {
    @Provide
    ImageUtil imageUtil() {
        if (isTest) {
            return TestImageUtil();
        } else {
            return PicassoImageUtil();
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions?

update: in picasso's code, attempting to use an `Executor` instead of  `ExecutorService`, I got stuck on `service.shutdown()`.

Answer (score 5):

I'm going to give you the general method for waiting on asynchronous tasks using espresso, because you can be sure that this will come up again.

You shouldn't use thread sleeping to wait for things to happen. This can cause flakiness, and causes your tests to be less efficient.  Espresso was designed with avoiding sleep calls in mind.

You also shouldn't force something to be on the main thread that isn't normally on the main thread. If this causes an ANR your test could fail because of the unexpected dialog pop-up. There could also be a real bug that only happens while multi-threading, but now that you're forcing something to execute on the main thread, your tests could miss it.

You're on the right track swapping out a different wrapper for Picasso for testing. What you need is a way to hook on to when the request gets started (right before it goes off the main thread), and when the request gets finished. Swapping out a wrapper is one way to do accomplish that.

To get notified of when the request is finished, you can use the [callback version of the into method.](https://square.github.io/picasso/2.x/picasso/com/squareup/picasso/RequestCreator.html#into-android.widget.ImageView-com.squareup.picasso.Callback-)

Now that you have the entry and exit points of your asynchronous task, you can use the CountingIdlingResource to keep your test from moving on until the task is finished. It's as simple as incrementing the counter before the task starts, and decrementing it when it finishes.

Here's a great example of how to use that class: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/testing/+/android-support-test/espresso/sample/src/androidTest/java/android/support/test/testapp/AdvancedSynchronizationTest.java?autodive=0%2F%2F

Comment: I was using `IdlingResource` to make api calls, but there was some kind of issue with `onClick` (can't find the post on SO anymore...) Very good point about the potential ANR!

Comment: @eski both of the links are dead

Comment: @BenPearson I fixed the picasso one (and you fixed the espresso one), thanks!